# Only pull request specified change

Tags: github, pull-request

I forked one repository and did some personal changes to origin master (such as: adding some scripts for automated compiling).

After that I created new branch (based on origin master which has personal changes) to fix issue. Synchronized origin master with upstream. Then I would like to pull request this branch only. But when I do pull request, all the personal changes are included as well.

Following is my steps/commands:

1. First I committed my personal changes to origin master

   > ```
   > git checkout master
   > git commit -m "personal changes"
   > git push origin master
   > ```
2. I fixed some bugs

   > ```
   > git checkout -b fix_bug_branch
   > git commit -m "fixed some bugs"
   > ```
3. Synchronized with upstream

   > ```
   > git fetch upstream
   > git merge upstream/master
   > git push origin master
   > ```
4. Rebased branch on to origin master & pushed it

   > ```
   > git checkout fix_bug_branch
   > git rebase master
   > git push origin fix_bug_branch
   > ```
5. Log-in to github and do the pull request. I notice that all the personal changes are included as well.

How can I only pull request the fixing issue branch, leave the personal changes in my origin master.

Comment: Pull request where? Github, Bitbucket, etc?

Comment: it is github @CoryKramer

Comment: Make sure your fix branch starts from upstream/master, i.e. the master of the original repo, not from master, i.e. your master, containing unrelated commits. Rebase your fix branch interactively on upstream/master, and choose to include only the commits needed to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, rebase on upstream/master solve my problem.